# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 doesn't DEBUG or RUN

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I know this might sound stupid, but I can't run my codes.

I'm just starting and had to install Visual Studio 2019 as school suggestion, but the teacher just runs the code and I can't, I just see what you see below:

[What shows in my Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FiP6.png)

My teacher's:

[Usually there´s this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3L0e.png)

Is there a way to fix t or I just screwed my installation?

UPDATE:

[0 Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqaFa.png)

Comment: You need to create a project. It looks like you just have a CS file right now.

Comment: It happens when I create a brand new project with a new solution, doesn't matter if the solution is in the same Folder or not.

Console Application for C#, doesn't matter if it's with .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 5.0

Comment: Open Visual Studio with no files/projects opened then to go file -> open project then browse for your `.sln` file linked with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try right clicking the project in the solution explorer toolbar, then selecting "set as startup project". This should enable the debugger and allow you to run using F5.

Comment: I have 0 projects to select from, and when I click on Properties to select a Startup project the list is blank